# Как достать ссылку из href='link'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, lxml

Допустим, существует элемент:

```
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>
```

Как мне получить в переменную `http://example.com/elsie`?

Прочёл официальную документацию, ответа не нашёл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример с первой же страницы документации:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ аж на двух площадках разом :D.

Comment: @AgeofCreations [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Таймаут пока. Сейчас отмечу.